# Laravel 4 - Input::old for standard select HTML

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im trying to list all years from 1970 until the current year without having to come into the code each year and update it.

I am using the following code to achieve this, but i am unsure of how to use the Input::old('year') with it.

```
$currentYear = date("Y");
$years = range( $currentYear, 1970 );

echo '<label for="year">Year</label>';
echo '<select name="year" id="year">';
echo '  <option value="">Please Select</option>';
foreach( $years as $year ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try using Input::old('year')?does it gives any error??

Comment: Where though? ... Im not even sure where to put it

Comment: Yes in know in my view file ... but where?

Comment: Hmmm ... that doesnt make sense though ... Doesnt the Input::old() statement, push the value selected back into the select box after validation has failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to re-populate a form after checking it for validation errors (in this case the select input) what you can do is first create a method in a Model (or somewhere else where it suits you) that generates the year range like this

```
 public static function getRange()
 {
   return array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1970), range(date("Y"), 1970));
 }
```

The code above will produce an array like this one (from current year to 1970)

```
Array ( 
[2013] => 2013 
[2012] => 2012 
[2011] => 2011 
[2010] => 2010 
[2009] => 2009 
[2008] => 2008 
...
[1970] => 1970)
```

Then in your view you can create the select input using the `Form` class

```
<?php echo Form::select('year', Model::getRange());?>
```

The first parameter is the name and the second one accepts an array that will populate the select input, in this case we populate it from our "Model" by calling the getRange() method that returns the above array.

And then in your controller where you check the validation if an error happens

```
return Redirect::to('form')->withInput();
```

Here the `withInput()` method takes care of the old input and your form will have the correct selected option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that ... Where would you suggest i put the getRange function if i dont have a model for years?

Comment: @BigJobbies If for example I have a form for registering Cars, I would put that in the `Car` Model, it depends on the information that I am saving it doesn't mean you need to have a Year model. But you can also create just a class like a helper and declare it there if you don't want to declare it inside a model.